# How to highlight or underline a text of HTML in WebBrowers

Tags: html, vb.net

The Code of HTML:

```
 <font class=""question"">Q1;</font> <font class=""question"">What is your name? <input name=""Q"" id=""Q"" value="""" size=20 style=""color:#336600; border:1px solid #999999"" class=""TextField2""> <input type='hidden' id= 'aQ' value='FOX'></font>
```

The Code of VB:

```
Public Sub Underline()
    For Each a As HtmlElement In WebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
                If a.Id.StartsWith("aQ") Then a.OuterHtml = "<font style=""color:red""><u>" + a.GetAttribute("value") + "</font>" + a.OuterHtml
            Next
End Sub
```

The Code of the button I tried

```
Do Until WebBrowser.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Interactive
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        Underline()
```

But now, I want the browser can underline the "FOX" while clicked the button

I tried *DocumentText* and StreamWriter, still not work

Have any solution?

I can underline the value of html when i copy the html code = DocumentText, but now changed to browser, it doesn't work.

Comment: The WebBrowser control emulates the behaviour of a normal web browser and, consequently, cannot modify (the HTML code or anything else in) the pages it shows. To perform any modification you would have to have access the corresponding files (e.g., hosted in your computer) and modify the HTML code (e.g., via StreamWriter). Afterwards you can use the WebBrowser again to see the modify version.

Comment: This mean can't make it as live view?

Comment: Yes. When you use a browser you see the HTML code from "outside" and consequently you cannot modify it in any way (descriptive picture: it is hosted in computer A and you are in computer B being able to only see what is happening in A). PS: sorry about the delay in replying but I was suspended (and unable to post comments).

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use javascript. Then you can change appearance on the client side.

[Like this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_textdecoration)

Comment: How about show "FOX" in the Textbox? what should i do?

Comment: If you choose to use javascript again then:
    document.getElementById("TextBoxId").value='FOX';

Comment: Everytime you want to change something without loading data from server  you need to use something like JS. This can sometimes get very tricky...

Comment: value is not a member of HtmlElement

Comment: What "NEXT" column mean? I don´t really know what are you trying to do.

Comment: `code`Private Sub ToolStripButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton2.Click
        RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + "[" + Now + "]" + "Extracting..."
        'Dim sourceString As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(WebBrowser1.Url)
        ' WebBrowser1.DocumentText = sourceString
        Do Until WebBrowser.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Interactive
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        Underline()
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(RichTextBox1).value = "FOX"
    End Sub`code`

Comment: Well, I try to explain my situation and what i am going to do. Firstly, the html file cannot be modified WebBrowser, so I want to display Fox this value in to the richtextbox1 this component, but every html page around 3 or 4 this type of value. How can I do that?

Comment: Well I still can´t figure out what are you doing. I never used WebBrowser object but I´m pretty sure this `WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(RichTextBox1).value = "FOX"` won´t do anything.

Comment: This **ToolStripButton2_Click** event is on the server side. I thought you need something more like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_text_value2)

Comment: As @varocarbas said. JS (or any changes you want) needs to be part of that HTML file before you start extracting that page.

Comment: [picture](https://na.cx/i/728rf1.png) like this, I want my VB.net program Textbox can only display Fox

Comment: Im sorry but I can´t imagine what are you trying to do. You will have to show more of your code or edit this question so It´s absolutly clear what went wrong.

Comment: like this, but still can't show the text in textbox

Comment: I only want to get the value of FOX in the website